# Load external AS3 SWF or Assets via utility class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Still new to AS3 - I've been futzying with this for a while and can't figure out why it will not display the loaded SWF (it loads it I can see that via trace, but addChild in the onCompleteHandler does nothing.  Either I don't have a handle to the loaded childSWF or I'm totally lost.  No error msg is displayed, but the trace does show that "this" is not the stage or anything displayable, its the Util class instance.

What im trying to do is load an external swf onto a template swf file and then manipulate the loaded swf via AS3 (provided it has instance names on all the things I want to mainipulate like text fields and titles and buttons)

```
package com.foo.flashas3
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import fl.motion.MotionEvent;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var childSWF:MovieClip;
        public var swfURL:URLRequest  = new URLRequest("some.swf");
        public var util:Utils=new Utils();

        public function Main()
        {
            // constructor code

            trace("Entering Main");
            trace(this);
            initSplash();
        }


        public function initSplash():void
        {
            util.getSubClip(swfURL);
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
package com.foo.flashas3
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Utils extends MovieClip
    {
        private var mLoader:Loader;
        public var mContent:MovieClip;
        public function Utils (){
            trace("Utils Constructor")
        }

        public function getSubClip(mRequest:URLRequest)
        {
            trace ("In getSubClip")
            mLoader = new Loader();
            mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
            mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
            mLoader.load(mRequest);
        }



        private function onProgressHandler(mProgress:ProgressEvent)
        {
            var percent:Number = mProgress.bytesLoaded / mProgress.bytesTotal;
            trace(percent);
        }

        private function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
        {
            trace("In onCompleteHandler")
            mContent = MovieClip(mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.content);
            trace(mContent.totalFrames);
            trace(this)
            trace(this.parent)
            addChild(mContent);
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is to addChild mContent to the util Object. And the util is not addChilded to anything, so mContent is not displayed.
There are many ways you could fix this.
One of them is to pass a reference to the object you want to add the swf to :

```
package com.foo.flashas3
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import fl.motion.MotionEvent;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var childSWF:MovieClip;
        public var swfURL:URLRequest  = new URLRequest("some.swf");
        public var util:Utils=new Utils();

        public function Main()
        {
            // constructor code

            trace("Entering Main");
            trace(this);
            initSplash();
        }


        public function initSplash():void
        {
            util.getSubClip(swfURL, this); // add reference to current object
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
package com.foo.flashas3
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Utils extends MovieClip
    {
        private var mLoader:Loader;
        public var mContent:MovieClip;

        private var target:Sprite; // <- object to add loaded swf

        public function Utils (){
            trace("Utils Constructor")
        }

        public function getSubClip(mRequest:URLRequest, target:Sprite)
        {
            this.target = target; // <- store target reference
            trace ("In getSubClip")
            mLoader = new Loader();
            mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
            mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
            mLoader.load(mRequest);
        }



        private function onProgressHandler(mProgress:ProgressEvent)
        {
            var percent:Number = mProgress.bytesLoaded / mProgress.bytesTotal;
            trace(percent);
        }

        private function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
        {
            trace("In onCompleteHandler")
            mContent = MovieClip(mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.content);
            trace(mContent.totalFrames);
            target.addChild(mContent); // <- add swf to target
        }   

    }
}
```

Note: I could not test the code, but if it do not run, you get the idea ...

Comment: Thanks djib - that set me on the right track and showed me I need to better understand the displaystack and interaction with it.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way of doing this?  From what I can tell FLA's associated to a class via the properties box, seem never to have the stage ready unless you add a sprite (not a movieclip - to be tested)